# how to show webView with address bar and bottomtoolbar buttons like safari

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, safari

i want to make my web view with address bar at top and with bottom bar buttons like safari, i used safari in place of web view but i cannot customise the size of safari,actually i want to show tabbar at bottom , i did this by adding safari browser on another view and then added to my main view as subview but always my tab bar hides behind the browser, so i want to show it on my web view like this [image]

can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello, I'm making an app looks like safari, I want to know how to use safari in place of webview?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
[webview goFarward];
[webview goBack];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build a compound view and write the code to glue together everything (webview, buttons, address bar, search bar).

EDIT: Added minimal example:

FullWebView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FullWebView : UIView

@end
```

FullWebView.m:

```
#import "FullWebView.h"

@interface FullWebView ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView* webView;
@end

@implementation FullWebView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setup
{
    UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 40);
    [self addSubview:backButton];
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - 40)];
    [self addSubview:self.webView];

    //Glue code for back button
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void) backTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.webView goBack];
}

@end
```

Comment: Added a minimal example that glues together a back button and a webview. Result is a custom UIView class that has both the webview and the back button. Of course what you need is a lot more than that. You're looking at about full day of coding to obtain a reusable full featured browser window component.